# How to run multiple tasks, handle exceptions and still return results

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am updating my concurrency skillset. My problem seems to be fairly common: read from multiple Uris, parse and work with the result, etc. I have [Concurrency in C# Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030171.do). There are a few examples using GetStringAsync, such as

```
static async Task<string> DownloadAllAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var downloads = urls.Select(url => httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));

    Task<string>[] downloadTasks = downloads.ToArray();

    string[] htmlPages = await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);

    return string.Concat(htmlPages);
}
```

What I need is the asynchronous pattern for running multiple async tasks, capturing full or partial success.

1. Url 1 succeeds
2. Url 2 succeeds
3. Url 3 fails (timeout, bad Uri format, 401, etc)
4. Url 4 succeeds
5. ... 20 more with mixed success

waiting on DownloadAllAsync task will throw a single aggregate exception if any fail, dropping the accumulated results. From my limited research, with WhenAll or WaitAll behave the same. I want to catch the exceptions, log the failures, but continue with the remaining tasks, even if they all fail. 
I could process them one by one, but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of allowing TPL to manage the whole process? Is there a link to a pattern which would accomplish this in a pure TPL way? Perhaps I'm using the wrong tool?

Comment: How do  you like to handle exceptions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I want to catch the exceptions, log the failures, but continue with the remaining tasks, even if they all fail.

In this case, the cleanest solution is to change what your code does for each element. I.e., this current code:

```
var downloads = urls.Select(url => httpClient.GetStringAsync(url));
```

says "for each url, download a string". What you want it to say is "for each url, download a string and then log and ignore any errors":

```
static async Task<string> DownloadAllAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var downloads = urls.Select(url => TryDownloadAsync(httpClient, url));
  Task<string>[] downloadTasks = downloads.ToArray();
  string[] htmlPages = await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
  return string.Concat(htmlPages);
}

static async Task<string> TryDownloadAsync(HttpClient client, string url)
{
  try
  {
    return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Log(ex);
    return string.Empty; // or whatever you prefer
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool stephen, Much better answer than mine(+1) :)

Comment: Stephen, many thanks. Is there any particular reason that you use static methods in your examples here and in the book? Just more succinct and easier to get running in an example solution? Or another reason?

Comment: Yes. The tech reviewers asked about that, too. :) I kept the methods `static` because they subtly enforce the notion that `async` methods work best without state.

Answer (score 4):

You can attach continuation for all your tasks and wait for them instead of waiting directly on the tasks.

```
static async Task<string> DownloadAllAsync(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    IEnumerable<Task<Task<string>>> downloads = urls.Select(url => httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).ContinueWith(p=> p, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously));

    Task<Task<string>>[] downloadTasks = downloads.ToArray();

    Task<string>[] compleTasks =  await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);

    foreach (var task in compleTasks)
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)//Or task.IsCanceled
        {
            //Handle it
        }
    }

    var htmlPages = compleTasks.Where(x => x.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        .Select(x => x.Result);

    return string.Concat(htmlPages);
}
```

This will not stop as soon as one task fails, rather it will wait for all the tasks to complete. Then handle the success and failure separately.

Comment: you can do `foreach(var task in compleTasks where task.IsFaulted or task.IsCanceled)` so you don't need to check the completed tasks. untested of course.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Let's leave that error handling part to OP, he gave us no clue about how he needs to handle the failure.

Comment: In this solution, how we can understand which url fails? I mean from Task object, how can i get original url? (Solution of Stephen is good, but for some reasons i want to do logging outside  of method that receives data. Thanks

Comment: @ALalavi You can use a custom type with URL and Task or use a map like `Dictionary<Task,string>` to find the failed task. If you need further clarification, you can ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks @Sriram. For now, i've changed " Log(ex);  return string.Empty; " ==> " return 'Error ' & url " . This way i can examine returned string, if it starts with 'Error' then i can log, if not then result string is ok for use. In above comment, I was asking maybe there is a better way by accessing Task itself.